# Извлечение кубического корня на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно просто считать число с клавиатуры и извлечь кубический корень, но обычными способами это не получается сделать т.к возведение в степень 1/3 числа к примеру 64 выдает 3,999999999... вместо нужного 4. Как это сделать?

Comment: `3.999999999` - можно считать вещественным представлением `4` в мире чисел с плавающей точкой. Так что все правильно. Вот еще попробуйте: `print(0.1 + 0.2)`

Comment: Не совсем понял строчку кода

Comment: А что делать конкретно с моим случаем когда нужен нормальный корень, а не это?))

Comment: что есть нормальный корень? `4 - 64**(1/3)` выдает мне `4.440892098500626e-16`, т.е. `0.00000000000000044`. Если хотите можете округлить: `round(64**(1/3), 6)`

Comment: Не считаю данный вопрос дубликатом, т.к. автор спрашивает - что нужно сделать, а не почему так получается.

Comment: Не вижу повода для переоткрытия. Если у автора появится вопрос об округлении вещественных чисел до ближайшего целого - пусть сформулирует явно вопрос.